# Test for equal variability in mixed model setting

Tags: mixed-model, variance, multivariate-analysis, levenes-test

I have a setting where I normally would model the variability in measurements by a linear mixed model which would look in R as follows.

```
require(lme4)
lmer(measure ~ equipment + (1|operator) + (equipment|batchid), data=mydataset)
```

So basically

- a fixed effect of equipment
- random intercept per operator
- random intercept per batch, differing for each type of equipment

Now in this model, I would like to define a test, which checks whether the variability explained by the equipment (fixed effect + random effect) changes by equipment level. There are 2 equipment levels and a unit based on which data is collected is called a batch.

Where can I find the specification of such a test?

Comment: This model doesn't give you a random intercept for `equipment`, but rather a random slopes of `equipment` that alters the random intercept for `batchid`. (a random intercept and a random slope for the same effect wouldn't make that much sense, I guess)

Comment: You are right, I misnamed it in the text. It is a random intercept for the batches, which differ by equipment. So as there are 2 equipments, 2 random batch effects, one for each equipment. I edited the question.

Comment: So what do you wanna test exactly? If there is a significant effect (i.e., difference) between the two equipment levels? And don't forget that your model also estimates an overall mean (i.e., intercept) in addition to the effects mentioned.

Comment: I want to test if the variability explained by the equipment parts of the model are the same for the 2 equipments.